# Odoo report field data is "Undefined" when expected False

Tags: python, sql, report, odoo, odoo-10

I have modified [crm_opportunity_report](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/851356bf2388c21ec5d6f68a505d067a4f758d3b/addons/crm/report/crm_opportunity_report.py#L8) :

- added a boolean field `is_customer = fields.Boolean('Is customer', readonly=True)`
- added a field to the view

  ```
  CREATE VIEW crm_opportunity_report AS (
      SELECT
          <...>omitted<...>
          rp.customer as is_customer
      FROM
          "crm_lead" c                        
          LEFT JOIN "res_partner" rp ON rp.id = c.partner_id
          <...>omitted<...>                
      GROUP BY c.id, stage.name, is_customer
  ```

After this in the report when I click "+" and choose "Is customer" sometimes value `Undefined` appears as a value for it.

**Tried this:** `COALESCE(rp.customer, FALSE) as is_customer` (and the same in Group by) but "Undefined" is still present.

**How in Odoo report I can make `Undefined` mean `False` so that when it's "Undefined" appears "False"?**

*Note:* when debugging with Firefox I can observe that from the server comes (jsonrpc) data with either "is_customer: false" or "is_customer: true" on items of report. But somehow those items that have "is_customer: false" on the report view are displayed *as if* "is_customer: Undefined".

**Update**

Somewhat accidentally I stumbled upon this [line](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/2d12ae3202ed93a12e1f8ff59bf64e82c0c98871/addons/web/static/src/js/views/pivot_view.js#L509)

```
if (value === false) return _t("Undefined");
```

**What might be the reason behind this logic: 'if value is false return "Undefined"'**?

*Funny part, I can add `if (value === true) return _t("Whatever");` :)*

Comment: Is it possible that some leads in your report do not have a `partner_id` and are this undefined instead of `False`?

Comment: @travisw That is right, some leads have no partner_id and so they cannot have `is customer` (set to true) because "customer(boolean)" field comes from `res_partner`. 
Anyway those should have False either because of `COALESCE(rp.customer, FALSE)` . And they have...  But in report false values appear as "Undefined" .

Comment: Can you instead use `COALESCE(rp.customer, 'f')`? As you found, Odoo will translate `False` to "Undefined", but it ought to translate `'f'` to "False" since that's how it stores in the database.

Comment: @travisw Thank You:). I tried and the result was the same. 'f' and FALSE in Postgresql are both **valid literal values for the "*false*" state** same https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-boolean.html :/ . I also tried to change field's is_customer datatype to fields.Char and it didn't give (with 'f') "False" in Odoo  either. This is Odoo 10. Are you referring to Odoo 10 :)?

Comment: @travisw if I tried adding `fields.Char` for `is_customer` and `CASE rp.customer
                            WHEN TRUE THEN 't'
                            WHEN FALSE THEN 'f'
                            ELSE 'f'
                        END as is_customer` to SQL then I get 'f' and 't' in report. But this is not the same because `Char` is not `Boolean` :/ : in Odoo filter in case with `fields.Char` will appear filter for `Char` and not for `Boolean`.

Comment: Strange enough: but in crm_opportunity_report there is a field `active = fields.Boolean` and this field has filter as if it is boolean. But my field `is_customer = fields.Boolean` ... appears in filter as if its char. I guess it's because field 'active' in report with current data has `true` for each entry in report's data. While in report's data there are entries with `is_customer` values `false` or `true`.

Comment: It’s not ideal, but you could create a kind of computed copy/dummy field on `res.partner` that stores a `Char` version of the `Boolean` field. Such as `is_customer_string = fields.Char(‘Is a Customer? (text)’, compute=‘_compute_is_customer_string’)` where the compute method just checks if the field is True and stores as `’t’` or `’f’` depending on that.

Comment: @travisw Thank you :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s not ideal, but you could create a kind of computed copy/dummy field on `res.partner` that stores a `Char` version of the `Boolean` field.

Take this for example where the compute method just checks if the field is True and stores as `'t'` or `'f'` depending on that.

```
is_customer_string = fields.Char('Is a Customer? (text)', compute='_compute_is_customer_string', store=True)

@api.multi
@api.depends('is_customer')
def _compute_is_customer_string(self):
    for partner in self:
        partner.is_customer_string = 't' if partner.is_customer else 'f'
```

[Documentation on computed fields](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/reference/orm.html#computed-fields)

<sup>Note: `store=True` is probably optional, but if you store the field, then you must use some `depends` field as a trigger to recompute. If you don't `store` the computed field, then the `depends` should be left off.</sup>

Comment: Ty. :) In case of store=True will the existing records have this field with value or only those that are created?

Comment: Assuming your `compute` method works properly (no errors) when you install/upgrade your module, then it will apply to all records, old and new. If for some reason you install/upgrade your module and it fails before completion, then it will have the field stored in the database, but without values. In that case, the easiest way to recompute is to (carefully) drop that column (`ALTER TABLE res_partner DROP COLUMN is_customer_string`) and then re-upgrade your module.

Comment: Thank you:)! I have another question though: in Odoo pivot reports field values are treated as strings?:)

Comment: I believe so, but I'm not sure I entirely understand your question

Comment: In Odoo pivot reports is there any difference if I return all values to report as strings (even if they internally are booleans, integers, etc.)? :)

Comment: It's definitely possible Odoo might treat them different if returned as strings. I would see it primarily being an issue for integers and floats since those have mathematical operations done on them during manipulation of the pivot table. I would have to try it though to know for sure.